# How can i get the price and order id on opercart 2.1.0.1

Tags: javascript, opencart2.x

I need to get the `order_id` variable and price variable without tax and shipping to put into a script on affiliate pixel.
How can i get this variables to set in this script?

e.g. something like the following:

```
//apypxl.com/ok/7077.png?actionpay={{Cookie_actionpay}}&apid={{transactionId}}&apprice={{transactionTotal}}&width=1&height=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `Order id`, Each time you select Payment method (Checkout) the order id is changed and inserted in to database as `order_status_id=0`(Missing Order)

If the customer confirms checkout then `order_status_id` is changed to Default Order Status

to see the session data (`current order_id`)

```
//system/library/session.php
print_r($this->session->data)
```

to see the cart info

```
//system/library/cart.php:319
print_r($this->cart->getSubTotal());
```

Comment: but if i need to put in a variable to give me the values how can i put it?